# No stack trace in Visual Studio

Tags: c, windows, dll, visual-studio-2015, stack-trace

I am trying to compile my university project originally written for compiling with GCC using MSVC. I've created solution and a handful of projects. One project contains the code for shared library used by the rest of the projects of the same solution.  Both the shared library and the rest of the projects compile.

When I try to run any of the projects which rely on the shared library, I can see the message in the output window which says that symbols were loaded, but then the code breaks on an error which I can only interpret as "not finding the function" in the shared library (literally it says "access violation").

The stack trace looks like this:

```
    ucrtbased.dll!<Unknown function>    Unknown
>   test2.dll!<Unknown function> Line 19    C
    assignment14.exe!<Unknown function> Line 37 C
    assignment14.exe!<Unknown function> Line 50 C
    assignment14.exe!<Unknown function> Line 64 C++
    assignment14.exe!<Unknown function> Line 255    C++
    assignment14.exe!<Unknown function> Line 300    C++
    assignment14.exe!<Unknown function> Line 17 C++
```

The project is written entirely in C, no C++, not sure why it says C++ there.

This is the contents of output window:

```
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\wvxvw\Documents\uni\test2\test2\Debug\assignment14.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\wvxvw\Documents\uni\test2\test2\Debug\test2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'assignment14.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown at 0x0F180E6A (ucrtbased.dll) in assignment14.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00A5D6F9.
```

I don't even know what direction to look at, so, if you need more info on my setup, I'll gladly provide it.

Comment: @kaylum it is in debugging mode, that's how I can see the "call stack" window, I can also add breakpoints etc. Or is there some other debug mode? I cannot see values of the variables though, or maybe I just don't know how to do it...

Comment: Do you get to (and can successfully break on) `main()`, or is the program crashing before you even get to main?

Comment: Did you build the debug configuration?

Comment: @cremno Visual Studio Express 2015.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It seems like I can get into main and can execute some code, although it's hard to tell whether it breaks on something specific inside the DLL, or just doesn't find something. When I try to "watch" variables, it says "unimplemented", and I don't know what that means.

Comment: @kaylum when I press on the green play button, left of it it says "Debug", does this mean I've built a debug configuration?